# Creating style css to tr for the table data

Tags: html, css, styles

I have created an HTML page. In which I am having a table which shows customer's Data. Now I wanted to call a style which will call table row which background, I am calling that but I am missing something due to which tr doesnot show row background. Also I am trying to add space between rows but not between column but I am getting space between both column and rows.

For an example, I have added background to two `<tr>`

```
<style type="text/css">
        td.tableHeader
        {
            color: #003678;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-family: Open Sans;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: inherit;
        }
        tr.background
        {
            bgcolor: #D0D1CB;
        }


        </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',verdana;">

<table class="wrapper" bgcolor="#E8E9E2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
    <!-- ============ HEADER SECTION ============== -->
        <td colspan="2" style="height: 100px;" bgcolor="#777d6a"><h1>Website Logo</h1></td>
    </tr>
</table>



<!-- ============ (CONTENT) ============== -->


 <table class="wrapper" bgcolor="#E8E9E2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
        width="100%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="tableHeader">
                Table header
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="wrapper" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center" >
                   <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="background" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" width="500" align="center">
                                <tr bgcolor="#D0D1CB">
                                    <td>
                                        Full Name
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Abc BCA
                                    </td>
                                </tr >
                                <tr bgcolor="#D0D1CB">
                                    <td>
                                        Phone Number:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        2314568970
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Email Address:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        abc@gmail.com
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        CustomerID:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        5566778
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<table width="100%" style="cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<!-- ============ FOOTER SECTION ============== -->
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center" height="20" bgcolor="#777d6a">Copyright ©</td></tr>
</table>
</body>

<html>
```

Comment: Try to simplify your question. I read this a few times and wasn't 100% clear with what your problem is.

Comment: @Acidic What you didn't understood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bgcolor` only as an inline attribute, but not as a styling parameter. What you're looking for there is `background` or `background-color`.

You'll need to remove a few attributes from the parent `table` element, like `cellspacing="3"`, which is giving you the space you see around table cells. If you remove this attribute, you can add a border, with the same color as your background, to the table cells; which will separate them in the way you need. See code snippet below:

```css
td.tableHeader {
  color: #003678;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: inherit;
}
tr.background {
  background: #D0D1CB;
}

.dataTbl td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e8e9e2;
}

.dataTbl tr {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',verdana;">

<table class="wrapper" bgcolor="#E8E9E2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
    <!-- ============ HEADER SECTION ============== -->
        <td colspan="2" style="height: 100px;" bgcolor="#777d6a"><h1>Website Logo</h1></td>
    </tr>
</table>



<!-- ============ (CONTENT) ============== -->


 <table class="wrapper" bgcolor="#E8E9E2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
        width="100%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="tableHeader">
                Table header
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="wrapper" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center" >
                   <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="background dataTbl" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center">
                                <tr class="background">
                                    <td>
                                        Full Name
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Abc BCA
                                    </td>
                                </tr >
                                <tr class="background">
                                    <td>
                                        Phone Number:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        2314568970
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Email Address:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        abc@gmail.com
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        CustomerID:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        5566778
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<table width="100%" style="cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<!-- ============ FOOTER SECTION ============== -->
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center" height="20" bgcolor="#777d6a">Copyright ©</td></tr>
</table>
</body>

<html>
```

```
table.background.dataTbl {
    border-spacing: 0 3px;
}
```

```css
table.background.dataTbl {
    border-spacing: 0 3px;
}

td.tableHeader {
  color: #003678;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: inherit;
}
tr.background {
  background: #D0D1CB;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',verdana;">

<table class="wrapper" bgcolor="#E8E9E2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
    <!-- ============ HEADER SECTION ============== -->
        <td colspan="2" style="height: 100px;" bgcolor="#777d6a"><h1>Website Logo</h1></td>
    </tr>
</table>



<!-- ============ (CONTENT) ============== -->


 <table class="wrapper" bgcolor="#E8E9E2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
        width="100%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="tableHeader">
                Table header
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="wrapper" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center" >
                   <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="background dataTbl" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center">
                                <tr class="background">
                                    <td>
                                        Full Name
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Abc BCA
                                    </td>
                                </tr >
                                <tr class="background">
                                    <td>
                                        Phone Number:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        2314568970
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Email Address:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        abc@gmail.com
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        CustomerID:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        5566778
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<table width="100%" style="cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<!-- ============ FOOTER SECTION ============== -->
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center" height="20" bgcolor="#777d6a">Copyright ©</td></tr>
</table>
</body>

<html>
```

Comment: Thanks but your td and tr messes up my header and footer

Comment: In what way @user131799? When I take the code you've provided in your question and place it in a new snippet for the sake of comparison, I see no difference between the header and footer of both variations.

Comment: It doesn't I realized that there is also td and tr in my header and footer on my original file and that is the reason I am facing that. Do you have any other option?

Comment: Thank you that worked forgotten about adding it as datatbl. Appreciate that.

Comment: Great! You might also want to try `table.dataTbl {border-spacing: 0 3px;}` and see which one you prefer. You won't need the `td` and `tr` styles if you do.